# Learning Ruby. Using Lynda.com. data_set not showing up terminal

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, dataset, terminal, gnome-terminal

I understand that the title was very vague and my apologies.  I am using Lynda.com to learn Ruby and am using 1.9.2 on Ubuntu 11.10.

Anyway.  While following this tutorial I have purchased the example files for reference.

Following the Arrays section of this tutorial it tells me to type in stuff, and I'm to expect the same answer he gets.  However.....

I don't.

If you look at the screenshot they are not the same.  Video is on the left, terminal is on the top right, the example file is on the bottom right. I am not getting the expected results.  I have checked in the terminal settings and I don't see anything that I'm missing.  Please advise.

Also, I cannot post images because I am below 10 posts.  Please copy and paste the link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p51K0.png

Comment: Purchased? I am sorry for that, my friend. And if it doesn't work - why don't you get your money back? Everything you need to learn Ruby you can find on Ruby web site here - http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/   ... it works and it is free!

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I used that to download Ruby and everything.  It's only 40$ a month at Lynda and I plan on learning much more than Ruby.  Thanks again though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]There is a typo in the irb where you are testing the code. It should have been:

```
irb> data_set = []
irb> data_set = ["a","b","c"]
```

but you have mistyped it as `data_set['a","b","c"]` thats why its messing up. Notice that you have enclosed `a` in wrong set of quotes. See my image (ruby 1.9.2, Win 7)

Comment: I just checked to see what you were talking about and I did not mistype it.  I copied and pasted your entry just to see if was possible I did make a mistake and I am getting the exact same thing.

Comment: Makes sense now!  Why didn't it fix itself when I entered it in correctly the time?

Comment: because due to the `'` was not closed everything that you were typing went into some nested level. & irb was not knowing. That was what you experienced when you were doing it second time, had you closed the `'` before second time you tried, you would have got the correct output.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Makes perfect sense.  Once I get 15 rep I will come back to this page and upvote you!

Comment: Man of my word.  Thanks again!